# Why private virtual member function of a derived class is accessible from a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, private-members, member-access

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
#include <iostream>
    
class Base {
public:
  Base() {
      std::cout << "Base::constr" << std::endl;
      print();
  }
  virtual ~Base() = default;

  void print() const { printImpl(); }
  
private:
    virtual void printImpl() const {
        std::cout << "Base::printImpl" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:        
    Derived() {
        std::cout << "Derived::constr" << std::endl;
    }
    
private:
    void printImpl() const override {
        std::cout << "Derived::printImpl" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base* ptr = new Derived();
    ptr->print();
    delete ptr;
}
```

The above code will print the following:

```
Base::constr
Base::printImpl
Derived::constr
Derived::printImpl
```

but I don't understand why `printImpl` **private** function is accessible from the base's `print` function. In my understanding `this` pointer implicitly passed to the `print` function holds the derived object's address, but I thought private member functions could be called ONLY from the member functions (and from `friend` functions) of the same class and here, `Base` class is not the same class as `Derived`, although there is an `is a` relationship.

Comment: Within a class, privates are accessible.  So base's `print` function has access to base's `printImpl`.  The benefit in doing this kind of *non-virtual interface idiom* is that it separates out the public facing API (`print`), from the inheritance facing API (`printImpl`).

Comment: Access control restricts naming something (even implicitly via initialization or conversion syntax), but what you **named** was `Base::printImpl`.  Returning `&this->private_member` from a function doesn’t fail to provide “access” to the private member for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as @Eljay notes - `printImpl()` is a method, albeit virtual, of the `Base` class.  So, it's accessible from the base class. `Derived` merely provides a different *implementation* of it. And the whole point of virtual functions is that you can call a subclass' override using a base class reference or pointer.

In other words, `private` only regards access by subclasses; it's meaningless to keep something `private` from a class' base class: If a method is at all known to the base class, it must be a method *of* the base class... a virtual method.

Having said all that - note that the `Derived` version of `printImpl()` is effectively *inaccessible* from `print()` - when it's invoked within the base class constructor. This is because during that call, the constructed vtable is only that of `Base`, so `printImpl` points to `Base::printImpl`.

> I thought private member functions could be called ONLY from the member functions of the same class

And indeed, `print()` is a member of `Base`, which invokes `printImpl()` - another method of `Base`.

Comment: My question was a bit different: I understand that `Base` class's `print()` member function can assess `Base`'s private `printImpl()` function, but as a overriden `printImpl` function is **PRIVATE** in the `Derived` class, I thought that compiler will say something like: "you can't access private member function which is outside of scope of `Derived` class". I guess a compiler doesn't "see" the actual object to which `ptr` points to and because of that there isn't any compile error.

Comment: There is only one `printImpl()` method - even if it has different implementations. I'll try to clarify this a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The private function of base class is not accessible in the derived class, but it can be overriden, since these two are separate concepts.

For the `print` call from the constructor of the `Base` class, [there is a following rule](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors):

> In a constructor, the virtual call mechanism is disabled because overriding from derived classes hasn’t yet happened. Objects are constructed from the base up, “base before derived”.

P.S. In general calls to virtual functions from constructors or destructors better be avoided

Answer (score 0):

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
Base* ptr = new Derived();
```

These are the effects of the above statement:

**Step 1**) An object of type `Derived` is created on the heap using the **default ctor** `Derived::Derived()`.

**Step 2**) Before entering the body of the default ctor `Derived::Derived()`, the compiler imlicitly calls the default ctor `Base::Base()`. Thus we get the output:

```
Base::constr
```

**Step 3**) Next, the statement `print()` inside `Base::Base()` is encountered. This statement is equivalent to writing:

```
this->print();
```

Hence, the `print()` function of class `Base` is called.

**Step 4**) Inside the `print` member function of `Base`, the call statement`printImpl();` is encountered. This statement is equivalent to writing:

```
this->printImpl();
```

But note that currently, the construction of the subobject of type `Base` is going on. Meaning the `Derived` part of the whole object has not yet been constructed. So even though the `printImpl` is a virtual member function and the call is made through a pointer, the ***virtual mechanism is disabled*** at this point. And thus the `this->printImpl()` calls the `Base::printImpl` version instead of the derived version of `printImpl`. This happened because the derived class has not yet been initialized. Thus we get the output:

```
Base::printImpl
```

**Step 5**) Finally, the body of the default ctor `Derived::Derived()` is executed. And hence we get the output:

```
Derived::constr
```

**Step 6**) The pointer `ptr` points to the `Base` part of the newly created derived object.

---

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement:

```
 ptr->print();
```

Now, from [this pionter's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this):

> When a non-static class member is used in any of the contexts where the this keyword is allowed (non-static member function bodies, member initializer lists, default member initializers), the implicit **`this->` is automatically added** before the name, resulting in a member access expression (which, **if the member is a virtual member function, results in a virtual function call**).

So, when you wrote:

```
ptr->print();  //this is equivalent to writing (*ptr).print();
```

The above statement is equivalent to writing:

```
(*ptr).print();
```

This means that the *address of the object to which the pointer `ptr` points*(which is nothing but `ptr` itself) is **implicitly passed** to the **implicit `this`** parameter of the `print` member function.

Now, inside the `print` member function, the statement containing the call to  `printImpl()` is  equivalent to:

```
this->printImpl();
```

according to the [quoted statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) at the beginning of my answer. And from the same quoted statement, since the member `printImpl` is a **virtual member function**, the expression `this->printImpl()` results in a *virtual function call*, meaning it results in calling the derived class `printImpl` function. And hence we get the output:

```
Derived::printImpl
```

Comment: I thought that compiler will say something like: "you can't access private member function which is outside of scope of `Derived` class" (as we access it from the `Base` class and the function is **PRIVATE**). I guess a compiler doesn't "see" the actual object to which ptr points to and because of that there isn't any compile error. Am I right?

Comment: The latter part of your answer is sometimes correct. the call `this->printImpl()` may be calling the base class' implementation, even if the object being constructed is a Derived object - as does actually happen in the sample code.

Comment: @DavidHovsepyan When the static and dynamic type through which the call is made differ(call is made through a pointer or a reference) and the member function is virtual member function then, [dynamic binding](https://www.codingninjas.com/blog/2021/09/25/static-binding-vs-dynamic-binding/) happens(which happens at runtime instead of compile time).

Comment: @AnoopRana Thanks a lot. You answered to my question.

Answer (score -1):

The reason that in the code you have `Base::printImpl` printed is because it is called from constructor of `Base`. The derived class wasn't constructed yet, so all calls to virtual functions will be referred to `Base`'s versions.

After construction the calls to `print` will akways redirect towards derived class's version. Whether functions are marked `private, public, protected` is inconsequential here.